# How to combine orderBy with multiple eager loaded relationships?

Tags: laravel

I have a model where I use `with()` method to eager load multiple relationships. Considering the code below, how could I use `orderBy()` method to apply different sorting rules for 'images'(order by priority) and 'price' (order by price), for example?

```
$model = $class::where('id', $id)
    ->with('brand', 'images', 'price')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort data of relations like this:

```
$model = $class::where('id', $id)
    ->with([
        'brand',
        'images' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('priority', 'asc');
        },
        'price' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('price', 'asc');
        }
    ])
    ->firstOrFail();
```